# When sending a package without closing, getting an error

Tags: java

When I try to send packages in my game about the coordinates of the player without closing anything, I get this error:

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 74000632`

That happens when host/client tries to send a package. Also, when I get that error, it points at line with `ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());` What to do? (I am just confused, please help)

Code for hosting:

```
static void hosting() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket hoster = new ServerSocket(9876);
        System.out.println("-1");
        Socket client = hoster.accept();
        System.out.println("-2");
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        while (true) {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            if (message.equals("Connected")) {
                game.add(otherPlayer);
                connected = true;
                continue;
            }
            otherX = Character.digit(message.charAt(0), 10);
            otherX *= 10;
            otherX += Character.digit(message.charAt(1), 10);
            otherX *= 10;
            otherX += Character.digit(message.charAt(2), 10);
            otherY = Character.digit(message.charAt(3), 10);
            otherY *= 10;
            otherY += Character.digit(message.charAt(4), 10);
            otherY *= 10;
            otherY += Character.digit(message.charAt(5), 10);
            otherPlayer.setBounds(otherX, otherY, 50, 50);
            oos.flush();
        }
    }
```

Code for client:

```
static void client() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9876);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject("Connected");
        connected = true;
        game.add(otherPlayer);
        while (true) {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            otherX = Character.digit(message.charAt(0), 10);
            otherX *= 10;
            otherX += Character.digit(message.charAt(1), 10);
            otherX *= 10;
            otherX += Character.digit(message.charAt(2), 10);
            otherY = Character.digit(message.charAt(3), 10);
            otherY *= 10;
            otherY += Character.digit(message.charAt(4), 10);
            otherY *= 10;
            otherY += Character.digit(message.charAt(5), 10);
            otherPlayer.setBounds(otherX, otherY, 50, 50);
            oos.flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling getInputStream in a loop?

Comment: Try put ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()); out of loop.

Comment: @Tix It actually worked! Thanks! (Please type it in answers so I can set it as working answer for me) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put `ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());` out of loop.